# Unable to set width for a PDF documents in MigraDoc library

Tags: c#, .net, migradoc

i am encounter a problem with the zoom level of the PDF.when i open the document By default,it showing with a zoom level of 25% because of page width(185). This can make the document look too small on the screen.
what i given is -
`Document document = new Document(); Section section = document.AddSection(); section.PageSetup.PageWidth = Unit.FromCentimeter(185);` 
what i need is- when i open pdf document it should take the browser zoom level

Answer (score 0):

The `PdfDocument` class has members like `ViewerPreferences`, `PageLayout`, and `PageMode` that allow to specify how a page should be displayed when opened in a PDF viewer. Not all PDF viewers may support open actions.

Note that the sample code in the question shows the MigraDoc `Document`, not the PDFsharp `PdfDocument` object which will later be generated by the PDF renderer.

Additionally, PDF files can contain "open actions" that execute when a file is opened. Not all PDF viewers may support open actions.

Here is a sample that shows how to set a PDF to fit vertically:
https://pdfsharp.net/wiki/WorkOnPdfObjects-sample.ashx
(Note: This links to the official PDFsharp site.)

Comment: @KJ Right. There was a time when Adobe Reader was installed as an add-on to the browser and was used to display PDF files. Long story short: There are many PDF viewers nowadays and most browsers have their own solution and I admit I cannot tell which browsers pay attention to display preferences set in the PDF, yet there are ways to set display preferences in the PDF files.